# Framework to quickly generate an Android app that just shows a big image (zoomable, scrollable)

Tags: gratis, android, open-source, framework, image-viewer

Let's say I have hand-drawn a cute map of my neighbourhood's park, and I want Android users to have it on their smartphone for offline use. I could tell them to download the file at a URL, but it would be too complex, most casual users are not even able to find a file they downloaded.

So, I would like to make this image an app.

Requirements:

- Input: Image file, app name
- Output: Android project ready to compile
- Zero coding
- Image can be zoomed, scrolled
- Supports very large images, like 4000x4000
- Free to use
- Generated app is releasable as open source (no proprietary libraries)

Bonus, not required:

- Automatic publication to Github and Play via their respective APIs.
- Compatibility with even old versions of Android

Answer (score 1):

Five years ago, I used to write a framework that did exactly this, but unfortunately it stopped working after Android 1.6. Anyway, I will mention it here as a possible source of inspiration:

https://code.google.com/p/androidbigimage/

You just had to execute the script with the image and name as arguments, for instance:

```
./generate_application.sh my_shiba_park_map.png "Shiba Park map"
```

Then you only had to compile the generated Android app.
License: GNU-GPLv3